# Using compressed memory under Miniconda container

Tags: docker, virtual-memory, zram

I am using [`continuumio/miniconda3:latest`](https://hub.docker.com/r/continuumio/miniconda3) as the base image for my container. It looks to be debian based. I run it under [Amazon Linux 2](https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-2/). **I would like to optimally use compressed memory, perhaps *zram*, in the miniconda3 container in privileged mode**. The container has access to 4 to 128 vCPUs and 6 GiB to 3.7 TiB of RAM, depending upon the job at hand. For what it's worth, the container doesn't seem to currently have systemd. My motivation is that the container has a large amount of unused CPU resources but insufficient memory for a big data job. Ideally I would want 2:1 or if possible 3:1 the virtual memory as the physical memory.

For what it's worth, the container has a `/proc` filesystem, and it also has privileged mode access in case it's relevant. The host has a `/proc` filesystem that has been mounted into the container at `/host/proc`.

What is the best way for me to update my docker image and container to optimally configure compressed memory using all vCPUs, preferably without hardcoding the amount? In principle I'd like to execute an entrypoint script, perhaps to [configure and enable zram](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/blockdev/zram.html).

Comment: I believe memory compression is a kernel feature, not a Docker feature. How much real memory do you have, and what problems are you having?

Comment: @harrymc Regarding it being a kernel feature, I have now added a paragraph with info about the `/proc` filesystem. The real memory is about 3.7 TiB and there are 128 vCPUs available for de/compression. The problem is that `pandas` is running out of memory despite valiant attempts to minimize its memory usage. In general though, using compressed memory would be great because it would result in significant cost savings for many memory-bound jobs even when the container is not running out of memory.

Comment: You are serious about physical memory of 3.7 TiB and 128 physical CPUs? This would make it a supercomputer. And that's not enough for one program?

Comment: @harrymc It appears that due to various Pandas bugs, indeed the memory has proven insufficient. I will however switch to another tool.

Answer (score 1):

Memory compression is a kernel feature, not a Docker feature.
In most operating systems, this feature is enabled automatically.

You cannot configure compressed memory in the Dockerfile installation.

If you stated your real problem and the real physical data about your computer,
we might be able to help.

Comment: I believe this answer in its current form to be less than useful because the Dockefile can in principle copy a script into the image which runs when the container is started to [configure zram](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/blockdev/zram.html). The question has been updated to clarify this goal.

Comment: Docker is isolated from the host operating system and cannot allocate real zram.

Comment: As I have noted in the question, the container is running in privileged mode, with `rw` access to both `/proc` and also independently to the host's `/proc`. These permissions should be more than sufficient.

Comment: Why do you think that access to `/proc` is enough to modify kernel parameters?

Comment: What is required? `/sys` can be similarly accessed and mounted. Let's find a way to get this working instead of finding reasons for it to not work.

Comment: You misunderstood - it's most likely working already. I think we need to restart from basics: (1) What operating system is the host? (2) Can you add your Dockerfile to the post? (3) What is your computer model and how much real memory does it have? (4) What errors are you getting? (5) What are the Docker memory settings? (a screenshot will help)